# How to get the value of <select> through id?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

For a Project I have to make a Table which you can live edit, delete and so on.

Right now the part of my code I have problems with is this:

```
$('#add').click(function()
    {
        var html  = '<tr>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data1"><select><option value="s">S</option><option value="a">A</option><option value="p">P</option><option value="v">V</option><option value="ü">Ü</option></select></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data6"></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data7"></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data8"></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data9"></td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable id="data10"></td>';
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Einfügen</button></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#insert', function()
    {
        var startart = $('#data1').text();
        var kennzeichen_id = $('#data2').text();
        var pilot_id = $('#data3').text();
        var begleiter_id = $('#data4').text();
        var startort_id = $('#data5').text();
        var startzeit = $('#data6').text();
        var landeort_id = $('#data7').text();
        var landezeit = $('#data8').text();
        var dauer = $('#data9').text();
        var bemerkung = $('#data10').text();

        if(kennzeichen_id != '' && pilot_id != '' && begleiter_id != '' && startort_id != '' && landeort_id != '' )
        {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:"insert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ 
                startart:startart, 
                kennzeichen_id:kennzeichen_id, 
                pilot_id:pilot_id, 
                begleiter_id:begleiter_id,
                startort_id:startort_id, 
                startzeit:startzeit, 
                landeort_id:landeort_id, 
                landezeit:landezeit,
                dauer:dauer, 
                bemerkung:bemerkung
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
                $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
                fetch_data();
            }
            });
            setInterval(function()
            {
                $('#alert_message').html('');
            }, 5000);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Kennzeichen, Pilot, Begleiter, Startort und Landeort sind min. benötigt");
        }
    });
```

The add function at the top is used to add a new row to my table, and the insert function below is used to insert it into my table.

I can already enter text with a text-field, but I have to change it so I can use a dropdown menu to select Items instead.

I added a select-tag with options to choose one of the Items and it gets displayed. But no matter what I choose the value that is inserted in my Table is the first of the options.

I hope I displayed my problem and some of you can help me.

Edit: Picture of what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Problem is that `id` attribute __must be unique__ on the page. Use classes instead.

Comment: Consider `$('#data8')` - what element should be selected? First? Second? Fourth?

Comment: I added a picture to clarify. For now I just want to get the selected value of the first column added to my database, but no matter what I select it enters "S".

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.
I had to change:

```
        var startart = $('#data1').text();
```

to:

```
        var startart = $('#data1').val();
```